# Not understood return behavior of recursive function with closure

Tags: recursion, return, closures

The foundations of my programming "skills" are shaking.. I don't know if this behavior is caused by the recursion, closure or something else, but this is by far the weirdest thing I've seen so far.

My original intention was to use recursion to count the parents of dom element. The closure is implemented to store my counter and recursion would increase it for every parent that is not equal to div#wrapper. And it works - once. For the first element (having only 1 parent - it returns 1) However the second time it returns undefined. for the sake of testing I came up with this rig:

```
let parents = countParents();
let pathLength = parents(3);

function countParents() {
    let counter = 0;
    return function nextParent(node) {
        let parent = node - 1;
        counter++;
        if (parent === 1)
            return 'WATAFAK';
        else
            nextParent(parent);
    }
}

console.log(pathLength);
```

I am actually questioning my eyes (it's late, been programming for a while now), but this function returns undefined. HOW is that possible?

Comment: There's no return statement in the `else` branch.

Comment: Also, please tag any questions with the language you're working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countParents() {
    let counter = 0;
    return function nextParent(node) {
        let parent = node - 1;
        counter++;
        if (parent === 1)
            return 'WATAFAK';
        else
            nextParent(parent); // call nextParent(parent) and throw away result
        return undefined;       // invisible line in every function
    }

    return undefined;           // invisible line in every function (never reached)
}
```

If you wanted the result of the recursion to be the result you must add `return` in front of it. How it is now it's only for side effects and it's pretty much dead code.

Since the `else` branch doesn't return all functions have a invisible `return undefined,` just before its block ends.

Comment: But why doesn't it return when parent hits 1? One would think that once this condition evaluates, recursion or not - doesn't matter, because we return the specified value, in this case hardcoded 'WATAFAK'. I can in fact see (while debugging) that the recursion breaks on the return line, when the condition is met, because it returns and thus never again calls itself.

Comment: @Alex it does. It returns back to the callee which can be an instance of the same function that **doesn't have a return**. A `return` doesn't return for the whole bunch, just the one. Imagine having several `console.log('test')` in a function. If it were true that a return terminated the callee as well then you would only see one output since `console.log` returns and according to your logic the function that calls it should return as well. To get what you want you need to change the default case to `return nextParent(parent);` that way the result from `nextParent(parent)` will be returned.

Comment: So recursive behavior is the reason behind this. Now that you say about the hidden returns, it makes sense, because when the if condition is met, I return 'WATAFAK', but this only returns to the previous instance of nextParent, which called this instance, which on its own turn returns undefined, because I have not specified otherwise. Thanks man :)